# Full width background inside Bootstrap container on Safari

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I found a post here where the same question was asked before. I implemented the solution suggested there and it works fine with Chrome and Firefox. But when I tested it on Safari and Opera, I ended up with a long horizontal scrollbar. I'm not sure how to fix it since I've already added `using overflow-x: hidden` to the body. You can see it in action [here](http://www.kampuster.com).

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="level"></div>
  <div class="level purple"></div>
  <div class="level"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.container {
  width:960px;
  margin: 0  auto;
  border:1px solid black;
}
.level {
  height:100px;
  background: #bada55;
}

.purple {
  position: relative;
  background: #663399;
}

.purple:before, 
.purple:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: #663399;  /* Match the background */
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 9999px;   /* some huge width */
} 
.purple:before {
  right: 100%; 
}
.purple:after {
  left: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Is there a more basic problem you're trying to address with the pseudo-elements on the `.purple` element?

Answer (score 4):

I checked in the link(www.kampuster.com) you shared and found the problem with your code.

**Problem:**
In file `all/themes/bootstrap_kampuster/css/style.css`, you have provided `width: 9999px;` for classes `.homeBanner:before, .homeBanner:after` and `.countUpSection:before, .countUpSection:after` which is causing the whole problem and is not the right way to do it.

**Suggestion:**
Below is the approach I would suggest you to go with.
Here is a [pen](https://codepen.io/aby30/pen/EEoepP) to better illustrate the suggestion.

```css
.section-first, .section-third {
  background-image: url('http://www.kampuster.com/sites/default/files/bannerlogo_babson.jpeg');
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
.section-first-inner {
  background-color: rgba(83, 192, 183, 0.3);
}
.section-first, .section-second, .section-third {
/*   this is just to add height inplace of content */
  height: 600px;
  color: #ffffff;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.section-first-inner, .section-second-inner, .section-third-inner {
  padding: 20px 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  height: 100%;
}
.section-second {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>HTML</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main-container">
      <header id="page-header"></header>
      <div class="section-first">
        <div class="section-first-inner">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                Your content for section first goes here
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="section-second">
        <div class="section-second-inner">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                Your content for section second goes here
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="section-third">
        <div class="section-third-inner">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12">Your content for section third goes here</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting `width:960px;` on the `container` try setting view width: `width: 100vw;`

So the container css will be:

```
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0  auto;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just use .container-fluid class.

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="background-image:url('xample.jpg')">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">

                    your content here

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Full width background inside Bootstrap container!!

*If this is what you want* [(Example Demo)](http://jdoodle.com/h/68)

**Then simply use [Relative Lengths](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp) :**

**vw**  Relative to 1% of the width of the viewport*

**vh**  Relative to 1% of the height of the viewport*

I have only replaced 2 values in your code:

1. `.container {
         width:100vw;
       }`
2. `.purple:after {
     width: 100vw;   /* some huge width */
   }`

**Code:**

```js
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<
link rel = "stylesheet"
href = "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <
  script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" > < /script>

  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <
  script src = "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" > < /script>
```

```css
html,
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.container {
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.level {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #bada55;
}

.purple {
  position: relative;
  background: #663399;
}

.purple:before,
.purple:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: #663399;
  /* Match the background */
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  /* some huge width */
}

.purple:before {
  right: 100%;
}

.purple:after {
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="level"></div>
  <div class="level purple"></div>
  <div class="level"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, this is working for me.

add the below css, if doesn't work try adding important to them. And to get full width of container, add container-fluid class to particular container.

```
html, body {
    width: -webkit-fill-available;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```